# Regex: Handle an Optional url part with delimiter

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I am trying to match some url which are built up like so:

```
https://tenantName-dev.somedomain.com/somefile.js
https://tenantName-qa.somedomain.com/somefile.js
https://tenantName.somedomain.com/somefile.js
```

Note the last one that has no "environment" since it's prod.

my C# regex so far:

```
https://(?<tenantName>.+)-(?<environment>[^.]*).(?<rootDomain>[^/]+)/somefile.js
```

This mostly works but would not match the last one as it always expects a '-'.
If I simply make that dash optinal, then it would match something like 'https://tenant-.somedomain...' which is not good.

I tried looking at lookaheads and non capturing groups to express the fact that I want a '-' only if there is a tenant behind but haven't been successful.

Comment: What about `https:\/\/(?<tenantName>.+)(-(?<environment>[^.]*))?\.(?<rootDomain>[^\/]+)\/somefile.js`? https://regex101.com/r/VmDlFf/1

Comment: Try `https://(?<tenantName>\w+)[-.](?<environment>[^/]*)\.(?<rootDomain>[^/.]+)/somefile\.js`

Comment: too greedy so you depend on positional constuks of `-` in front and `.js` at end but do not acnt for domain that only has 1 dot, but yes ? you rely on greed for line-up wick is no good. all sugestunz are no good so far

Comment: user and @wiktor-stribiżew
Both of your suggestions allow me to match the following string, which is not acceptable

https://tenantName-.somedomain.com/somefile.js

Answer (score 1):

In most flavors of regex (*and in .Net's version*) there is an *conditional* pattern which allows for a check such as `if...then...else`. This is done by `(?({conditon})X|Y)` where if the match condition is true `X` is done or if not *then* `Y` is done).

Test it out by doing this (*note turn on the flag `IgnorePatternWhitespace` because I am commenting the regex*):

```
 (?(?:.+-)   # If a dash
  (?<A>.+)   # Match for dash
 |           # Else Then   
  (?<B>.+)   # Match this
)
```

So the condition is a lookahead which is `?:.+-` which means somewhere ahead there is a `-`. If true match on and create a named capture group `A`. Otherwise create a match on group `B`.

---

So taking your pattern we can distill it down and just focus on the `-`. Such as

```
https://
(?(?:.+-)    # If a dash
  (
    (?<tenantName>[^-]+)-(?<environment>[^.]+)
  )
 |           # Else Then   
  (
    (?<tenantName>[^.]+)
  ) 
)
\.(?<rootDomain>[^/]+)
```

So if we dump the match when there is a `-` the groups profile in the match looks like this:

```
Match #0
                    [0]:  https://tenantName-dev.somedomain.com
            ["1"] → [1]:  
            ["2"] → [2]:  
   ["tenantName"] → [3]:  tenantName
            →3 Captures:  tenantName
  ["environment"] → [4]:  dev
            →4 Captures:  dev
   ["rootDomain"] → [5]:  somedomain.com
            →5 Captures:  somedomain.com
```

Note the indexes above are valid of `[3]` or better to used the named capture of `["tenantName"]` which gives us "tenantName" and `["environment"]` which gives us "dev".

Take out the `-dev` and the match dump looks like this:

```
Match #0
                    [0]:  https://tenantName.somedomain.com
            ["1"] → [1]:  tenantName
            →1 Captures:  tenantName
            ["2"] → [2]:  
   ["tenantName"] → [3]:  tenantName
            →3 Captures:  tenantName
  ["environment"] → [4]:  
   ["rootDomain"] → [5]:  somedomain.com
            →5 Captures:  somedomain.com
```

For that `["environment"]` group is not represented and we can check `Success` as `mtch.Groups["Dev"].Success`. Example:

```
var pattern = @"https://
(?(?:.+-)    # If a dash
  (
    (?<tenantName>[^-]+)-(?<environment>[^.]+)
  )
 |           # Else Then
  (
    (?<tenantName>[^.]+)
  )
)
\.(?<rootDomain>[^/]+)";

var url = "https://tenantName.somedomain.com/somefile.js";

var mtch = Regex.Match(url, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

if (mtch.Groups["Dev"].Success)
   ...
```